# check the labels when calculating loss (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Consider this problem, I have an output vector like this:

`[0.1, 0.3, 0.6,    0.4, 0.1, 0.5,    0.6 , . . .]`

and target labels like this:

`[ 0 ,  0 ,  1 ,     0 ,  0 ,  1 ,    1  , . . .]`

the output and the target labels are three-by-three represent a specific label (i.e, logits `[0.1, 0.3, 0.6]` and related target label `[0, 0, 1]`),

In the original problem actually it's not 3, but 84 and the length of labels and output vector are very large (about 5 million) and in most cases (about 90%) the related labels has no 1, so there is no need to calculate the loss for that output,

now my question is, **how can I ignore that outputs which have no 1 in related labels?**

or in the other word **how can I check the labels during training when I want to compute loss?**

there is my loss function:

```
score_split = tf.split(1, 64800,  scores)
score_split_output = [tf.nn.softmax(c) for c in score_split]
output = tf.concat(1, score_split_output)
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(labels * tf.log(output), [1]))
```

I divide scores 84 by 84 `(5,443,200 / 64,800 = 84)` and give them to softmax, then concat and compute loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since may someone counters the same mistake I made, here is the solution. I want to check the labels during the loss calculation because there are lots of paired labels which take long to computation each of them by a separate Softmax function.

Then I reshape the logits and label vectors into `[-1, 3]`, and apply one Softmax on them:

```
    logits = tf.reshape(self.score, [-1, 3])
    labels = tf.reshape(self.y, [-1, 3])  
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

The choice of your input data depends on your problem, not of the details of your technical solution.

1. Either the data with no labels is something you will no encountered at test time. Then you should simply remove the data from your dataset. However the fact that you didn't is probably a sign that you can't because this data belongs there.
2. Or, if this data is something you will encounter and need to handle at test time, you need to keep it and learn on it. You could for example add a 85th label, that is 1 iff the 84 other labels are zero, and zero otherwise.

**EDIT**

Example of augmenting your labels:

```
import tensorflow as tf
labels = tf.zeros((100, 84))
label85 = 1-tf.reduce_max(labels)
new_labels = tf.concat([labels, tf.expand_dims(label85,-1)], 0)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I can't change the input data format, or ignore some labels, consider my problem as this way: takes half of a  high-resolution image as input and predict other half, pixel by pixel, so I want to predict each pixel, and some pixels will be empty, so related one-hot label has no 1 in that case

Comment: What I am saying is that you can dynamically add a 85th column to your input labels.

Comment: I catch it, of course, I can do it, but it doesn't make sense, I want to reduce the complexity of computation by ignoring(don't calculate loss for them) the labels which have no 1, but by adding 85th column, I'll have still the same computation complexity

Comment: OK, but then why can't you remove them from your input? What will happen at test time?

Comment: because they are not separate data, consider an image which has one object in the middle of it and a lot of empty spaces around (with label zero for empty pixels), but other images may have empty space in the middle and objects in corners.

Comment: Does it mean you will simply ignore the result on those samples at test time?

Comment: The only thing I want is that, when I want to calculate loss for each image, I want to ignore the computation loss for empty pixels,( not ignore whole of the image)

Comment: Aren't they already ignored in your cost function? You multiply the output by the labels, but the labels are zero for the samples you want to get rid of.

Comment: yes that's right, but since there are about 55000 zeros and only 10000 occupied pixels, it takes a lot of time to compute loss in each step (about 1 minutes), so I ask that, how can I stop computing loss for that empties.

Comment: Ah OK, that's clearer now :-) You want to skip computation on those samples while still providing them as an input. I don't see a way to achieve this.